# React - SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE JSON

Tags: json, reactjs, fetch

Estoy utilizando un json propio la cual saco de una ruta de mis carpetas.

En el modo de desarrollo funciona todo bien, pero al momento de hacer deploy me salta el siguiente error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON
```

Me lo estaria tirando al momento de entrar a la seccion "Works", la cual hace un fetch a dicho archivo json.

```
const Works = () => {
const [works, setWorks] = useState([]);
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true)
    fetch('/src/assets/js/works.json')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => {
            setWorks(response);
            setIsLoading(false);
        })
}, [])

return(
    <section className='works'>
        
        < TitleHeader title='works' />

        <div className="worksContainer">

            {
                !!isLoading ? < Loading /> :
                works.map(work => {
                    return(
                        <WorkCard key={work.id} 
                            id={work.id}
                            title={work.title}
                            subtitle={work.subtitle}
                            extra={work.extra}
                            main_image={work.main_image}
                            other_image={work.other_image}
                            />
                    )
                })
            }

        </div>

    </section>
)
```

}

SOLUCION:
Cambiando la ubicacion del json a la carpeta public como dice el comentario de abajo

Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Probaste poner el json en tu carpeta ``public`` y hacer un ``fetch('works.json')``?

Comment: deberias editar tu pregunta y pegar como tienes el json, tambien te sugiero que agregues `?` para que sea nullable tus datos, `id={work?.id}`

Comment: Gracias por responder, ahora edito

Comment: @AgustinG. de esa forma si me hace fetch al json pero no me reconoce los assets

Comment: y porque no pones la carpeta assets en /public tambien? Osea, tu archivo JSON esta tratando de encontrar las imagenes en un directorio ``./assets/...``, entonces lo que te comente ya te soluciono el problema. Ahora tenes que arreglar la ruta a las imagenes. O volviendo a poner ls assets al lado del JSON, o renombrando las rutas. Saludos

Comment: Si, muchas gracias Agustin por la ayuda. Abrazo